# Add additional fee on the total shipping fee

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way (a snippet) to add an extra fee on the total shipping fee. Want to add an extra $1.00 (for box cost) on the total shipping fee.

Instead of making it visible on front-end I just want to make that extra fee hidden and add it on the total shipping cost.

Say

Subtotal : $5.00
Shipping : $3.00 (total shipping is $2.00 + my extra $1.00 fee)

Total = $8.00

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer not to use a plugin, it looks like you will need to edit `includes/class-wc-shipping.php` Line 317.

[image: Code Snippet]

It appears that `$this->shipping_total += $rate->cost;` on Line 317 calculates the shipping total on a per-package basis (this is in a loop).

After the loop completes, you'll need to add your fee:

[image: Shipping Fee]

The code added on Line 327, `$this->shipping_total += 1;`, adds an additional, hidden fee to the total cost.

To add a hidden fee to the shipping line item, edit `includes/class-wc-cart.php` Line 1387 from:

[image: Original]

To...

[image: New]

This accounts for the AJAX call that drives shipping cost calculation.

Comment: I tried it but the shipping fee is still the same. But on the overall total fee it adds the $1 fee..

Comment: So it's like this?
Subtotal $3, Shipping $2, Total $6?

Comment: Yes your correct, it shows that result..Shipping fee should be $3 also.

Comment: Can you share a link, by chance?

Comment: Here. http://urbandigitalsites.com/safari/cart/. Try to order 1 product and it will give you a shipping fee of $16.04 and Total is 23.29. And now total shows 24.29 which is correct. But the shipping fee still the same.

Comment: Same happens on the first changes man, Shipping still the same, and now the total price is $25.29

Comment: as of the moment, i just use jquery to manipulate the shipping fee. Thanks for helping me man, if you could find out to solve the problem that will be awesome, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the **WooCommerce Extra Fee Options PRO** plugin fills this need, so yes it is possible.

Comment: Thanks man, i haven't check the PRO version of the plugin but it shows the extra fee on front end and it creates another field. I just want to add it on the total shipping fee.

Comment: Let me dig at the source real quick.